# JSP page form validation: 2 forms and 2 scripts

Tags: javascript, html, validation, jsp

I have two forms in my JSP page which should be validated by two embedded JS scripts (see code below). The trouble is that the scripts don't work properly and omit validating the first entries (username and loginName respectively). I had two external Javascript files to do the validation but that had a similar problem.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Scotia Login Page</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
            <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/stafflogin.js"></script>  -->
            <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/userlogin.js"></script>  -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/DWBA.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="header"><h1>Scotia Island & Wildlife Cruises</h1></div>
                <div class="box"><h2>Login Page</h2>

                    <script>
                        function validateform1() {
                            var username = document.stafflogin.username.value;
                            var password = document.stafflogin.password.value;

                            if (username === null || username === "") {
                                alert("Please enter the admin username");
                                document.stafflogin.username.focus();

                                return false;
                            } else if (password === null || password === "") {
                                alert("Please enter the admin password");
                                document.stafflogin.password.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <form name="stafflogin" action="CustomerServlet" onsubmit="return validateform1()"><!--  -->
                        <h3>Staff Login with username and password</h3>
                        <p> To login, enter details below:</p>
                        <table cellspacing="8" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><p>Staff Username:</p></td><!-- USERNAME is admin -->
                                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><p>Staff Password:</p></td><!-- PASSWORD is admin -->
                                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="stafflogin" name="submit" style="width:75px"  /></td>
                                <td><br /><input type="hidden" name="username" value="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <br />
                    <script>
                        function validateform2() {
                            var name = document.userlogin.loginName.value;
                            var password = document.userlogin.loginPasswd.value;

                            if (name === null || name === "") {
                                alert("Please enter your username");
                                document.userlogin.loginName.focus();
                                return false;
                            } else if (password === null || password === "") {
                                alert("Please enter your password");
                                document.userlogin.loginPasswd.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <form name="userlogin" method="POST" action="LoginServlet" onsubmit="return validateform2()">
                        <h3>Customer Login with login name and login password</h3>
                        <p> To login, enter details below:</p>
                        <table cellspacing="8" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><p>Login name:</p></td><!--  -->
                                <td><input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><p>Login password:</p></td><!--  -->
                                <td><input type="password" name="loginPasswd" id="loginPasswd"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="userlogin" name="submit" style="width:75px" /><br /></td>
                                <td><input type="hidden" name="loginName"  value="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <br />
                    <form name="Form" action="CustomerServlet">
                        <h3>New Customer registration</h3>
                        <p>To register, click on "register" below:</p>
                        <table cellspacing="8" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="register" name="submit" style="width:75px" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
<div class="footer"><div align="center"><!-- ALIGNS EVERYTHING WITHIN DIV -->
        <p>&copy; Copyright Scotia Island & Wildlife Cruises, Harbour Road, Morar, Invernessshire.</p>
        <form>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="home" name="submit" style="width:75px" /></td>
            </tr><br />
        </form></div>

</div><br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I am a novice at Javascript I need some help to work out why two separate forms and validation scripts won't work as expected. (I have other JSP pages with single external Javascript validation scripts and they all work as intended).
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: try the `focus()` using `document.getElementById("username").focus()` rather than `document.stafflogin.username.focus()`

Comment: Just tried your suggestion - no change. It still skips over the username validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to remove the hidden inputs from each form eg.

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="" />
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="loginName"  value="" />
```

so the forms look like this:

```
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                function validateform1() {
                    'use strict';
                    var username = document.stafflogin.username.value;
                    var password = document.stafflogin.password.value;

                    if (username === null || username === "") {
                        alert("Please enter the admin username");
                        document.stafflogin.username.focus();
                        return false;
                    } else if (password === null || password === "") {
                        alert("Please enter the admin password");
                        document.stafflogin.password.focus();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        document.stafflogin.submit();
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <form name="stafflogin" action="CustomerServlet"  onsubmit="return validateform1()">
                <h3>Staff Login with username and password</h3>
                <p> To login, enter details below:</p>
                <table cellspacing="8" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><p>Staff Username:</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><p>Staff Password:</p></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="stafflogin" name="submit" style="width:75px"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

and this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                function validateform2() {
                    'use strict';
                    var name = document.userlogin.loginName.value;
                    var password = document.userlogin.loginPasswd.value;

                    if (name === null || name === "") {
                        alert("Please enter your username");
                        document.userlogin.loginName.focus();
                        return false;
                    } else if (password === null || password === "") {
                        alert("Please enter your password");
                        document.userlogin.loginPasswd.focus();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        document.userlogin.submit();
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <form name="userlogin" method="POST" action="LoginServlet" onsubmit="return validateform2()">
                <h3>Customer Login with login name and login password</h3>
                <p> To login, enter details below:</p>
                <table cellspacing="8" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><p>Login name:</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><p>Login password:</p></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="loginPasswd" id="loginPasswd"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="userlogin" name="submit" style="width:75px" /><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

In short there was nothing wrong with the Javascript.